# Find including itself with jQuery (like closest but traversing down)

Tags: jquery, dom, find, element, traversal

Like [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) which allows traversing from the element itself up through its ancestors, I am looking for a method for traversing from the element itself down through its descendants (so unlike [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) which only traverses through the descendants, excluding the element itself). 
I had a look at [the list of traversing methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) and couldn't find what I was looking for.

**Is there a method in jQuery which is like `.closest()` but for traversing down?**

Comment: I don't underatnd your question, why find is not ok?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon because it doesn't include element itself as closest()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a plugin that will find the closest (including itself):

```
$.fn.findClosest = function(selector) {
    return this.is(selector) ? this.filter(selector).first() : this.find(selector).first();
};
```

The you call it like that :

```
$('#level-2').findClosest('.foo');
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/W3WCQ/12/

Comment: That works great, though I believe for the `jsfiddle` example to really illustrate `findClosest` you need 2 situations (1 where element itself is a match, and another where it isn't): http://jsfiddle.net/W3WCQ/13/

Answer (score 7):

Just use [addBack(selector)](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) method:

```
$(this).find('.myclass').addBack('.myclass').first();
```

`addBack('.myclass')` will add element itself **only** if matching the selector

Comment: I believe you need to use `.addBack('.myclass')` otherwise you always end up with the element itself, whereas the initial intention is to search for elements that match the class (while including the element itself in the search). See http://jsfiddle.net/W3WCQ/11/. Maybe you can help me further: I'm trying to create my own `findClosest` plugin based on `find + addBack` but for some reason it fails.

Comment: We're probably also missing a `.first()` somewhere to make sure we only return the 1st one found.

Comment: So you want only to return one element as closest or all descendants including element itself?

Comment: Yes, like `.closest`, but going down.

Comment: Ok so i misundertand your question